# Use mechanize to access a HTTP Basic authenticated webpage

Tags: python, mechanize

In my current program, i'm accessing a HTTP Basic authenticated page like this, which works perfect:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://test.localdomain/test.pl'
realm = 'Test DB'
username = 'foo'
password = 'bar'
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm, uri , username, password)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
data = opener.open(url).read()
```

Now i want to click a button on that page after logging in. I found the mechanize library for Python which can do things like that easily. Unfortunately, i couldn't successfully do the same basic authentication as above when using mechanize. This is what i tried:

```
from mechanize import Browser
url = 'http://test.localdomain/test.pl'
realm = 'Test DB'
username = 'foo'
password = 'bar'
browser = Browser()
browser.add_password(url, username, password, realm)
browser.open(url)
```

But then i get the following exception:

```
HTTP Error refresh: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an     
infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
OK
```

How can i fix this? Or can i let mechanize use the already working authhander created by urllib2 in my first snippet?

Comment: I tried many different URL-variants, none of them worked. with urllib2, everything is okay. so i wonder why the same url does not work with mechanize.

Comment: had a little error in my sample data, fixed... realm is the name of the authentication realm

Comment: Try catching the exception and just do a pass on it.

Comment: Thanks sukhbir! After reading your comment i realized that the error doesn't mean that i cannot access the page after opening the url. so everything works fine, except that the error is a bit annoying (it takes some time). i think the whole error is because the target page has an auto-reload every 3 seconds, which seem to bother mechanize.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The error can be ignored. When catching it, the program can regularly continue.

Answer (score -1):

My script was throwing the same error. Here's how I fixed it.

```
browser.add_password(url, username, password, realm)
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

You may need to use browser.click()to submit your form if there is one and/or create a "results site" variable and open that with urllib2.